# SQL Server 2000 Dump Statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, migration

Hi I'm migrating a few databases from sql 2000 to sql 2008.

while running upgrade advisor I got a message that says that there are objects with the Dump/Load sintax. that is not on use anymore.

So I found the following text in a proc

```
Dump DataBase @name to @path With Init
```

Further investigating I discovered that this was a backup and that the sintax is similar.

My doubt is: Can this be replaced to:

```
Backup DataBase @NomeBanco to @nomeBkp With Init
```

is a to disk required? (can this Dump be used to backup to tape when used without the to disk?)

Is there any difference between the two statements?

Whats the main difference between this commands.

Thanks
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [MSDN BOL says compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187315(SQL.90).aspx) for SQL Server 2005 (DUMP and be used instead of BACKUP)

> BACKUP supports the following keywords
>   to provide backward compatibility with
>   earlier versions of SQL Server:
>
> - The RESTART option is accepted for compatibility but has no effect in SQL
>     Server 2005.
> - To maintain backward compatibility, you can use the DUMP keyword instead
>     the BACKUP keyword in your BACKUP
>     statements. In addition, you can use
>     the TRANSACTION keyword instead of the
>     LOG keyword. The SQL Server Database
>     Engine interprets DUMP DATABASE or
>     DUMP TRANSACTION the same as BACKUP
>     DATABASE or BACKUP LOG, respectively.

So my conclusion would be it's valid for SQL Server 2008 given BACKUP stays the same as SQL Server 2005, except support for DUMP is removed

Comment: How about Backup Devices? Will it work normally (in comparison to sql 2000)?